# Chrome: Overcoming "file not commonly downloaded" warning

Tags: google-chrome

We are a software publisher. Our installer EXEs are signed with our code signing certificate issued by Thawte. Recently, our installers are being flagged as "####.exe is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous" --the call-to-action being discard.

These files do not have any malware in them. VirusTotal lists no error for the files.
These files were created newly but were signed using our certificate that is in use for the past 1 year

On what grounds is Chrome flagging this as "dangerous". How many downloads does it need to be completed before it is no more "uncommon"?

How can we prevent such a dialog from appearing in the future?

Comment: There are no warnings currently in our Google WebmasterTools also. Some discussion boards hint at incorrect MIMEtypes, but our MIME type is correctly set as `application/octet-stream`

Comment: The solution presented in [Publishing Application on Website](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60864/publishing-application-on-website) does not apply to use as our code is already signed.

Comment: Sorry but the question appears to be duplicate. A question is not made unqine because no relevant answers have been left, current answers can be edited and improved and new answers can be added at any time. So there is no need to create a 'new question'. We also have several ways of getting attention to old questions, through bounty rewards and upvoting.

Comment: Have you added your site twice? in Webmaster tools? as http:// and ftp:// will be treated as two different sites https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/34592?hl=en